# Access Parent Class Method from Child in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a small problem where I have parent class and child class. I want to modify the state that was initialized in parent class so that I can see updated state in parent class. Here's the code:

```
var Parent = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function(){
        return{
           my_value: 0
        }
    },

    _increaseValue: function(){
        this.state.my_value++;
    },

    render: function(){
        return(
            <div><Child /></div>
        )
    }
});

var Child = React.createClass({
    render: function(){
        //at button I want to access _increaseValue function of parent
        return (
            <div>
                 <button onClick={_increaseValue}>Increase</button>
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

Now when user clicks the button in child class I would like to get the updated `my_value` in parent class, thus my questions are:

1. Is it possible?
2. If yes, how it is done?
3. Is this good practice or no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. > Is it possible?

   yes, it is possible
2. > If yes, how it is done?

   you can pass parent method to child through `props`, like so

   ```
   var Parent = React.createClass({
     getInitialState: function(){
       return {
         my_value: 0
       }
     },

     onChangeValue: function () {
       var value = this.state.my_value + 1;

       this.setState({
         my_value: value
       })
     },

     render: function() {
       return <div>
         <Child 
           onChangeValue={ this.onChangeValue } 
           value={ this.state.my_value } 
         />
       </div>;
     }
   });

   var Child = React.createClass({
     _handleClick: function(){
       this.props.onChangeValue();
     },

     render: function(){
       return <div>
         <h1> { this.props.value  } </h1>
         <button onClick={ this._handleClick }>Increase</button>
       </div>
     }
   });
   ```

   [`Example`](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/37241/)
3. > Is this good practice or no?

   It is good practice

Comment: @Amir Al could you create fiddle with code where you use `props`?

Comment: @Amir Al ok, I understood

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass function via props into your child component. And when you need to change you call this function. It is normal practice and react way.

Example:

```
var Parent = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function(){
        return{
           my_value: 0
        }
    },

    onChildClick: function() {
        this.setState({
          my_value: this.state.my_value + 1
        })
    },

    render: function(){
        return(
            <div>
              {this.state.my_value}
              <Child onClick={this.onChildClick.bind(this)}/>
            </div>
        )
    }
});

var Child = React.createClass({
    _handleClick: function(){
        this.props.onClick();
    },

    render: function(){
        return (
            <div>
                 <button onClick={this._handleClick}>Increase</button>
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

[Example on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p0cwLyb2/)